# Angular cli not using global npm install

Tags: angular, npm, angular-cli, npm-install

I am new to npm and node, i am learning angular.

In an angular cli project, whenever i run ng <<'keyword'>> command, i am getting below error as its unable to find global npm-modules folder.

> node_modules appears empty, you may need to run `npm install`

Tried following configuration but no luck, i have to run npm install in every project to overcome the problem.

```
export NODE_PATH=/usr/local/lib/node_modules
PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin/node
PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin/npm
```

Is there way that i can avoid running npm install for every project?

Comment: did you installed Angular CLI globally with `npm install -g @angular/cli`, and install dependencies for this project by run `npm install` in your app folder (same folder with `package.json` file)

Answer (score 46, accepted):

I got the same error when I tried to run `ng serve` command after running `ng new myapp` and creating my project folder. This error occured because I didn't move in to the `myapp` folder I created. Once I used the `cd myapp` command and moved in to the folder `ng serve` worked successfully.

Answer (score 2):

**Follow the steps below**

**npm cache clean** and than **npm install**

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid node_modules appears empty, you may need to run error by doing
 run following command :
 `npm install -g@angular/cli`

It will solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

1- cmd > run **ng version** , to confirm that angular CLI was installed correctly

2- Be Sure that you are in the right folder/root (Probably is this your problem)

3 - then run : **ng serve**

Answer (score 0):

run `cd folder_of_your_project`

then run `ng serve`

Answer (score -1):

you need to be in the project structure folder to run **ng serve** or any other command once npm is installed  in your system.you can check **ng version** in your root folder though.In the latest angular cli version the file is renamed as package.json where all dependencies are present.